# What do I add to template.php so I can render regions in a page created in hook_menu()?

Tags: 7, theming

I need to recreate a lot of pages after removing Panels from a site.

In order to print regions in node tpls, I added this to `theme_preprocess_node`. That's fine but it doesn't work for custom pages.

```
// Get a list of all the regions for this theme
  foreach (system_region_list($GLOBALS['theme']) as $region_key => $region_name) {

    // Get the content for each region and add it to the $region variable
    if ($blocks = block_get_blocks_by_region($region_key)) {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = $blocks;
    }
    else {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = array();
    }
  }
```

I tried adding that to `theme_preprocess_page` but it doesn't do anything.

Here is my module. The divs print fine but the regions don't get printed.

```
function custom_pages_menu() {

    $items['classes-admin/%'] = array(
        'title' => t('Classes'),
        'page callback' => 'page_sidebars',
        'access arguments' => array('edit field_diary_date'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function page_sidebars() {
    $page_return = "";
    $page_return .= '<div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="panel-pane">';
    $page_return .=                     render($region['sidebar_left']); // or $page
    $page_return .=             '</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="panel-pane">';
    $page_return .=                     render($region['sidebar_right']); // or $page
    $page_return .=                 '</div>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';

    return $page_return;
}
```

This seems like a pretty common thing to do but google isn't giving me anything to work with. I don't want to add them to page.tpl because it's a very complex site and I only want it this way, if possible. Any help appreciated.

Comment: No idea what your code is trying to do here sorry. As far as I can see `$region` is undeclared/null in `page_sidebars()`. I can't see how this code can possibly work.

Comment: I know. My question is about what to add to template.php or something so it will work.

Comment: Ha, well I can see it isn't -1 anymore, and I like to think you wouldn't downvote your rules+views partner :) As for my edit, I thought the question reached the standards of SO, and my incorrect assumption that the solution would be lie within template.php would be a common one and searchable. I'm always impressed by your commitment here @Pierre.Vriens. I go through phases where I have time and I don't.

Comment: Merci for the feedback. My 2 (additional) cents: downvoting questions is cheap: the downvoter doesn't have to "pay" any rep decrease for doing so (like the -1 for downvoting an answer). Therefor, if an anonymous downvote of any of my questions comes in, I just ignore such downvotes, and move on (if the downvoter doesn't want to teach me what's wrong, then why bother, right?). Which is also why I think you should rollback your question to the prior revision, your choice of course. PS: sure this question doesn't need a drupal release indication? I.e. would you want to know answers for D7 or D8?

Comment: I didn't realise it was free to downvote a question, and I edited my post so I don't look so pissy. Not sure about D7 / D8.. I haven't played much with D8 yet and in general, things I assume would stay the same, generally don't. So I added the 7 tag. I'm off to bed. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, replace this line

```
render($region['sidebar_left']);
```

with

```
render(block_get_blocks_by_region('sidebar_left'));
```

and replace this line

```
render($region['sidebar_right']);
```

with

```
render(block_get_blocks_by_region('sidebar_right'));
```

hope it will work for your case :)

Comment: My main page.tpl.php is like 500 lines long.. And I'll need to create about 20 new tpls if I do it this way. That's a lot of effort and room for error every time I change the main tpl file.


I'd be really surprised if I can't print regions in hook_menu(). I'd print blocks but I want caching per block and only works with regions.

Comment: Well, then try this, replace this line  
**render($region['sidebar_left']);** with **render(block_get_blocks_by_region('sidebar_left'));** hope it will work for your case and similarly replace this line  
**render($region['sidebar_right']);** with **render(block_get_blocks_by_region('sidebar_right'));**

Comment: Awesome. That works perfectly. Can you edit your question to add that and I'll give it the tick and upvote?

Comment: @NiallMurphy I updated my answer :)